# Strange Haskell type error only happening when currying assertEqual

Tags: haskell

This code will compile correctly:

```
import Text.Printf
import Test.HUnit
doubleMe x = x + x
doubleUs x y = doubleMe x + doubleMe y
doubleSmallNumber x = if x > 100 then x else x*2
doubleSmallNumber' x = if x > 100 then x else x*2 + 1
conanO'Brien = "It's a-me, Conan O'Brien!"
main = do
  runTestTT $ TestList [TestCase $ ae 4 $ doubleMe 2,
                        TestCase $ ae 10 $ doubleUs 2 3,
                        TestCase $ ae 4 $ doubleSmallNumber 2,
                        TestCase $ ae 1000 $ doubleSmallNumber' 1000,
                        TestCase $ assertEqual "" "It's a-me, Conan O'Brien!" conanO'Brien]
  where ae = assertEqual ""
```

The output is:

```
$ clear && ghc baby.hs && ./baby     
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( baby.hs, baby.o )
Linking baby ...
ld: warning: could not create compact unwind for .LFB3: non-standard register 5 being saved in prolog
Cases: 5  Tried: 5  Errors: 0  Failures: 0
```

When I change the code to:

```
import Text.Printf
import Test.HUnit
doubleMe x = x + x
doubleUs x y = doubleMe x + doubleMe y
doubleSmallNumber x = if x > 100 then x else x*2
doubleSmallNumber' x = if x > 100 then x else x*2 + 1
conanO'Brien = "It's a-me, Conan O'Brien!"
main = do
  runTestTT $ TestList [TestCase $ ae 4 $ doubleMe 2,
                        TestCase $ ae 10 $ doubleUs 2 3,
                        TestCase $ ae 4 $ doubleSmallNumber 2,
                        TestCase $ ae 1000 $ doubleSmallNumber' 1000,
                        TestCase $ ae "It's a-me, Conan O'Brien!" conanO'Brien]
  where ae = assertEqual ""
```

I get:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( baby.hs, baby.o )

baby.hs:12:65:
    No instance for (Num [Char])
      arising from the literal `1000'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [Char])
    In the first argument of `doubleSmallNumber'', namely `1000'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `doubleSmallNumber' 1000'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `ae 1000 $ doubleSmallNumber' 1000'
```

I don't understand why.

Also does anybody have any ideas for fixing the ld warning:

```
ld: warning: could not create compact unwind for .LFB3: non-standard register 5 being saved in prolog
```

Comment: What operating system/architecture are you on? The linker included with Xcode for OS X 10.7 produces quite a few warnings in conjunction with GHC.

Comment: I am running Snow Leopard on a MacBookPro8,2.  I installed GHC with homebrew.  Would installing Haskell from source fix the ld warning?

Comment: I don't remember encountering linker problems on Snow Leopard, but I use the Haskell Platform installation for day-to-day hacking. It might be worth trying that, but I don't want to lead you on a goose chase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an example of the monomorphism restriction. `ae` "looks like a value" (doesn't have arguments) and doesn't have an explicit type, so compiler won't infer a polymorphic type for it.

In first example, it gets type `Int -> Int -> Assertion` (I think).

In the second, from `ae "It's a-me, Conan O'Brien!" conanO'Brien` it gets the type `String -> String -> Assertion`. Remember that the type of integer literals is actually `Num a => a`, and `1000` gets type `String` from `ae`, so the compiler needs an instance `Num String`.

EDITED: This can be fixed by giving an explicit type annotation: `where ae :: (Show a, Eq a) => a -> a -> Assertion = assertEqual ""`. Or by adding arguments to definition (eta-expanding it): `where ae x y = assertEqual "" x y`.

Comment: Excellent explanation.  I will give the function a type, and see what happens.

Comment: It is called the monomorphism restriction, not the polymorphism restriction (even though it restricts polymorphism).

Comment: Oops. I do know this, don't understand how I managed to misname it.

Comment: @augustss: One of these days I should hack GHC to add `-XPolymorphismRestriction` as an extension. Who needs monomorphic bindings, anyway? :]

Answer (score 6):

It's the monomorphism restriction.  The `ae` function is assigned a monomorphic type.  Either turn off the restriction or give `ae` a type signature.

Comment: How do I turn off the restriction?

Comment: You can pass -XNoMonomorphismRestriction on the command line or put `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 4):

@augustss and @Alexey Romanov are correct. You can see the inferred type for `ae` if you move it to the top level and remove the last assertion:

```
*Main> :t ae
ae :: Integer -> Integer -> Assertion
```

If you keep `ae` in the `where` clause, but add a type signature with a more general type, it will work:

```
main = do
  runTestTT $ TestList [TestCase $ ae 4 $ doubleMe 2,
                        TestCase $ ae 10 $ doubleUs 2 3,
                        TestCase $ ae 4 $ doubleSmallNumber 2,
                        TestCase $ ae 1000 $ doubleSmallNumber' 1000,
                        TestCase $ ae "It's a-me, Conan O'Brien!" conanO'Brien]
  where 
    ae :: (Show a, Eq a) => a -> a -> Assertion
    ae = assertEqual ""
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a footnote, it's *overloading* that's ruled out by the monomorphism restriction. So, this is ok

```
foo :: String -> b -> b
foo _ b = b

goo :: (Int, Bool)
goo = (moo 2, moo True) where moo = foo "boo"
```

but *this* isn't

```
hoo :: Eq b => String -> b -> b -> Bool
hoo _ b c = b == c

ioo :: (Bool, Bool)
ioo = (moo 2 2, moo True True) where moo = hoo "boo"
```

Parametric polymorphism is permitted (and has no performance overhead)!

Comment: Well, parametric polymorphism has performance overhead since it requires boxing (the way it's typically implemented), but we need that for lazy evaluation anyway.  But the performance hit is nothing like what you get with overloading.